# Call method in a view controller which is a parent of the parent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having some trouble calling a method in a different view controller.

Here's my setup:
ViewController1 -> ViewController2 -> ViewController3

ViewController1 calls ViewController2 using a WEPopoverController invocation:

```
UIViewController2 *viewCon2 = [[UIViewController2 alloc] init];

navPopover = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewCon2];
[navPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 57)
                               inView:self.view
             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                             animated:YES];
```

I would like ViewController3 to be able to call a method that exists within ViewController1. Since ViewController3 is not directly initialized from ViewController1, I couldn't figure out how to use the delegate method to call ViewController1's method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your ViewController1 `vieDidLoad` add the line ..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodFromViewController3) name:@"Message" object:nil];
```

**( do remove the observer in dealloc)**

then when you want to call the method in view 1 from viewcontroler 3..
Post the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Message"  object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

When you **post** the **notification** `methodFromViewController3` method is called in first view ( you have to add that in the view controller)... in your case.. you can just change it to the name of existing method that you would like to call..

Comment: Note that Notifications shouldn't be used for calling methods which is what I think the original poster was asking. Notifications are for special circumstances. See the link posted by @Alexander below for more details of this

Comment: i know his answer was better.. but why down vote me??...everything comes at its own pace....@sw333t doesn't know about notifications itself...you want him to take on the full doc explaining communication objects...it will confuse him more..

Comment: If he doesn't know about notifications, then that isn't the place to start. The place to start it with proper object design and building up the basics and progressing to more advanced topics like Notifications. Otherwise your answer implies that notifications are the default way of calling methods in other classes which is bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways for communication between classes, you can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html).

Comment: +1 For providing information that will teach the question asker many things that will be of benefit to them.

Answer (score 0):

If VC3 has a reference to VC2, and VC2 has a reference to VC1, you can do it like this in VC3:

```
ClassOfViewController2* vc2 = [self viewController2];
ClassOfViewController1* vc1 = [vc2 viewController1];
[vc1 myAwesomeMethod];
```

Comment: In doing that, all of your classes have to know about all the others in the chain. This is not very good.